# CSS rule is getting overridden

Tags: css

I created a photo gallery for my websites, and on my latest site I thought I'd contain the CSS and all page files in a sub-folder, thinking this would be easier because I could use it like a plug-in on other sites as opposed to having all the gallery CSS in the main CSS file as I have done in the past.

Here's the gallery page: http://unserclosecustoms.com/gallery/galleries.php

The problem now is, the H3 gallery headers are defaulting to Times New Roman instead of Trebuchet as called out in the gallery's CSS file (h3.gTitle).

I know something is overriding this but I'm not adept enough yet to figure out what. My hunch is that it's the separate CSS for the gallery that is conflicting with the site's main CSS file.

If I've missed anything, please let me know and I'll elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: Try using a development tool like Firebug (for Firefox) or the built-in tools in Chrome, Safari, or IE9+.  They have a view that shows the styles in use and how they were selected.

Comment: Peter, I do use Firebug, but tw16's answer fixed the problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the line below in your gallery.css file:

```
charset "utf-8";
```

It is missing an @ symbol:

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

Comment: technically @djjeck got the answer first. Perhaps they should get the accept?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the @ when declaring the charset.
Try

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

That parser error is also swallowing the first rule in your stylesheet.

Comment: Sorry! Good catch you too, though =D

Comment: djjeck, yep...that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `@` character before your charset declaration in the gallery.css file.

Comment: PJM...embarrassing, that fixed all!

Answer (score 0):

Put this include:

```
<link href="css/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

after:

```
<link href="../css/ucc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

There is probably some CSS declarations in ucc.css that are overriding your styles in gallery.css

Comment: Good idea, I'll check it out. Actually, see above, I was missing an @ before charset. Ugh...such simple things. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your .gTitle class in your CSS. Please take a look. ;)

Comment: it's in the gallery.css file. However, it was a simple screw up on my part, no @ before charset. Thanks!